# C# Entity Framework ANSI NULL OFF

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

We've created a WPF application that uses entity framework to connect with a database. In the database there are several stored procedures that I would like to execute. I've imported the stored procedure as functions in EF and everything seems OK, except it isn't. If I execute the stored procedure nothing happens in the database. If I execute the stored procedure in the SQL Server Management Studio, with the same data, then some rows are being processed as expected. That wasn't always the case. It only started to work in SQL Server Management Studio when I disabled CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS and ANSI_NULLS. How can I also make it work in the application itself?

Guido

Comment: have you tried Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand() before the sp call?

Comment: Your analysis is wrong regarding ANSI_NULLS. `When a stored procedure is created, the SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER and SET ANSI_NULLS settings are captured and used for subsequent invocations of that stored procedure.`. If any of the other options make a difference you are better off fixing the procedure to not rely on these options being `OFF`.

Comment: @Martin I agree that the stored procedures should be fixed. Problem is that I didn't write these procedures. They are part of a third party software solution and I don't want to change their code.

Comment: @Phil do you mean setting ANSI_NULLS to OFF by using the ExecuteSqlCommand before calling the sp?

Comment: Im just pointing out a  way to test what is required.  Analysing the root cause is step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem by using:

```
Context.ExecuteStoreCommand(@"
   SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
   SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON OFF
   SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
   SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
   SET ANSI_NULLS OFF

   exec sp params
")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Entity Framework 6 then we can set Ansi warning off but its scope is transaction , where ever you used sp or savechanges method you need to have this code and after that you need to dispose that transaction

```
DbContextTransaction _transactionContext;
_transactionContext = _Context.Database.BeginTransaction();
_Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF");
//Start:Below code is project specific
_Context.Entry(SBSB_SUBSC).State = entityState;
status = status + _Context.SaveChanges();
//End
if (_transactionContext != null)
    _transactionContext.Dispose();
```